# How to generate another form on checkbox select event using loop in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I created a form with validations to take member's details and register it. I want to create another form when user click on add another member by using it. Is it possible to have 2 form tag in one page in ASP.NET, and how to do it?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="webAss1.WebForm4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 59%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 112px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 112px;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            height: 29px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>MEMBER REGISTRATION FORM</h2>
    <p>
        Enter the details:</p>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Email:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Contact no:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Address:</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help

Comment: *A page can have only one server-side Form tag.*

Comment: so is it impossible to add another member ? @FarzinKanzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test another server side form in you page you will get this error:

> *A page can have only one server-side Form tag.*

But you can add another form without `runat="server`. That is a client side form. But I think it is useless. Maybe do some help for validations.(Of course client side validations with `$("#form_id").valid();`)